# How to toggle Modal and pass/change data

Tags: reactjs

I am new to reacting and having trouble understanding how to pass data meta into each modal when an image is clicked and update the modal with the clicked data info. Following in my bare minimum code for sake of example

app.js

```
   <div className="movie">
      <Modal >hello world/*making sure the static text is passed into as children prop*/</Modal>
        {movies.length > 0 &&
          movies.map((data) => {
            return <Library key={data.id} {...data} searchTerm={searchTerm} />;
          })}
      </div>
```

modal.jsx

```
export default function Index({children}) {
  const [isOpen, setIsOpen] = useState(true)
  return (
    isOpen && (
      <div className='modalContainer'>
      <div className="modal">
        <div className="close">
          <button onClick={()=>{
            setIsOpen(false)
          }}>close</button>
        </div>
        {children}
      </div>
    </div>
    )    
  )
}
```

Library.jsx

```
import "./Library.scss";
import {Link} from "react-router-dom";
const IMG_API = "http://image.tmdb.org/t/p/w1280";
const Library = ({
  title,
  poster_path,
  release_date,
}) => {
  return (
    <div>
      <Link to="/modal">
      <img src={IMG_API + poster_path} alt={title} />
      </Link>
      <div className="meta">
        <h5>{title}</h5>
        <p>{release_date.slice(0, 4)}</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

export default Library;
```

Answer (score 1):

You should declare the `isOpen` state in the upper-level component so you can actually open the modal on some kind of event.
Also, you should declare a props where to pass the actual text to the `Modal` component:

```
const [isOpen, setIsOpen] = useState(false)

const handleOpen = () => setIsOpen(true);

<div className='movie'>
  <Modal isOpen={isOpen} setIsOpen={setIsOpen} text='Hello, world' />
  {movies.length > 0 &&
    movies.map((data) => {
      return <Library key={data.id} {...data} searchTerm={searchTerm} />;
    })}
    <button type='button' onClick={() => handleOpen()}>Open modal</button>
</div>;
```

You should then change your `Modal` declaration as:

```
export default function Index({ isOpen, setIsOpen, text }) {
    return (
      isOpen && (
        <div className='modalContainer'>
        <div className="modal">
          <div className="close">
            <button onClick={()=>{
              setIsOpen(false)
            }}>close</button>
          </div>
          {text}
        </div>
      </div>
      )    
    )
  }
```

Comment: thanks, I got a problem when I set to `true` it reloads the page because I do not want to load the Modal upon page load

Comment: @localhost If you don't want the modal to open on page load set the default `isOpen` state to `false`

Comment: false makes the page reload when and doesn't load.